# How to open the Configure Launcher Icon window in the android developer tools (ADT)?

Tags: android, adt

I installed the ADT and have already created my project. But now I want to change the settings of the app icon in the Configure Launcher Icon window. But I cannot find where to open it.

Does anyone know?

If you don't know how it looks like:
See step 14 here http://setup-steps.blogspot.ca/2013/03/android-developer-tools-adt-bundle.html

Thanks.

Comment: What 'settings' do you want to change?

Comment: The additional padding and the icon itself.

Comment: The icon is under the `res/drawable-` folders as `ic_launcher.png`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you right-click on your project -> choose "New" -> choose "Other" -> open "Android" sub-tree -> choose "Android Icon Set", you'll find the wizard you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to a wizard that helps you build your initial application. It creates a generic icon and labels it ic_launcher.png and places it in each of your drawable folders.

If you want to change your icon just name your file "ic_launcher" and size it according to Google's [standards](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) and place it in each drawable directory. There is also a final file ic_launcher-web.png in the root of your project that you must replace as well.

If you want to use a generator to make your icon you can use the Android Studio Launcher Icon tool [here](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html). Just create it and follow my above steps for setting it up.

Finally a note from Google on proper icon sizes:

[image]